# Has this Google Maps imagery of 4 planes on a runway been tampered with?

Tags: landing

The image below is of Google Maps (30 May 2018) of Amsterdam Schiphol's Aalsmeerbaan (36R).

It shows 4 planes on the runway and a fifth that's about to land. When you zoom in, all planes seem identical.

Has this image been tampered with or could there be an explanation for this?

[image]

Comment: Just a note, but tamper strongly implies some kind of unauthorised/unlawful/nefarious alteration. If the planes aren't actually there, it's far more likely to be some kind of post-processing artefact rather than some kind of deliberate tampering.

Comment: By the way it is a good catch!!

Comment: If those are actually different planes, then the controllers at Schiphol are utterly failing at maintaining separation.

Comment: Sattelites photography are usually not actual photos but rather a compilation of multiples photos not necesserally taken at the same time.

Comment: @ManuH A lot of Google's photography is aerial rather than satellite. However, you're correct that it's not taken at the same time. The aircraft or satellite would fly in a line taking photos which would later be stitched together.

Comment: Link to the Google Map in question:
https://goo.gl/maps/KmtDUB4x7VK2

Comment: Didn't you know? The Netherlands has a group of 787s that not only do formation flying, they also do formation landing...
No, it's not a thing, but I _want_ it to be a thing.

Comment: Link to a question on the Photo.SE site about the same image: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95153/9161

Comment: Looks like Google's new 3D imagery satellite is in operation...

Comment: Some people have marked this question as off-topic.
In my opinion this question only _becomes_ off-topic after you know the answer. I'm not sure if that should make the question off-topic.

Comment: Personally I agree with the general assessment that this is off topic. you're asking "has been this image tampered?" i.e. something a informatic forensic investigator should answer, not a pilot or a mechanic.

Comment: True, point taken

Comment: It was on Photo.SE last December. The question got 200 views, seven votes and the best answer also seven. I guess aviation types like photos better than photographers do. Of course, they were looking at red channel mismatch instead of 'tampering'.

Comment: Since that's the date you saw the planes on Google Maps and not the date of their actual existence at the airport, I think writing down the date isn't really important.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Google Maps and Google Earth are made by stitching together many different images to create the illusion of a single massive picture of the globe.

The image you are seeing was almost certainly made by an aerial photography plane passing overhead of another plane landing.  In multiple snapshots, it captured the same plane on final, touching down, rolling out and stopping.

The images were assembled together to line up the ground and all static elements.  But items that are moving appear multiple times in different images.

Comment: Your answer makes so much sense that it makes me wonder why I didn't think of it myself. The spacing between the planes also supports your answer. You can actually see the plane slowing down.

Comment: I would have thought it might be satellite photos, but the same principle applies.

Comment: @CptReynolds Google uses satellite imagery when you're zoomed out and aerial imagery when you're zoomed in.

Comment: The southernmost plane in the sequence is also still in the air, so would never happen IRL (wake turbulence, ATC rules, etc). Someone could do some fancy math, assuming a 140 kt landing speed and confirm it's a satellite (and that there's one aircraft image missing from the stitching of the images.

Comment: @IanW It's most certainly aerial photography, satellite photography simply does not have an adequate resolution for images like these. Wake turbulence only applies to directly crossing the flight path; ATC requires something like a 2000ft vertical separation (my guess is that the surveyor flew at 7000ft, as flights at Schiphol are generally initially cleared to 6000ft)

Comment: Looking at the zoomed-in image, it's pretty clear that the survey plane takes three images (RGB) with three filters and then they are stitched together to get true colour - of course the stitching fails with a fast moving object.

Comment: No matter who or what took those photos... The amount of paperwork to get permission to take them above an big airport in full operation must have been epic.

Comment: [When going back further, you can see the plane a sixth time.](https://www.google.at/maps/place/Flughafen+Amsterdam+Schiphol/@52.1788452,4.7697806,781m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c5e134e0fd162d:0xc7d51583f1cef188!8m2!3d52.3105386!4d4.7682744)

Comment: @Tonny Not necessarily.  In the US, the airspace over major airports isn't restricted at all altitudes. At the major airports around New York City, the [class B airspace only extends to 7000 feet](http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=40.491&lon=-80.233&zoom=10)

Comment: @Sanchises: *satellite photography simply does not have an adequate resolution for images like these* -- commercial satellite tech, sure. But [spy satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KH-11_Kennen#Image_gallery) can probably do even better.

Comment: @mgr326639 There is whole class of jokes about google image stitching, eg look up "stealth train uncloaks"

Comment: @MattD Those photos are from Schiphol (AMS). Airspace there is very tightly controlled. When I was still flying sport and small business planes (20 years ago) it was a major pain in the a** to get permission to overfly the airport. Getting landing clearance was actually much easier so I got in the habit of making a short stop at AMS as part of the Amsterdam sightseeing flight. Since AMS only got busier and noise/environment regulations (which restrict flight corridors) stricter I image getting clearance now is even more difficult.

Comment: @MartinBonner that could be, but to me it looks like a classic case of Chromatic Aberration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration which is a physical effect that occurs in the lens of the camera.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that some pains have been taken to digitally alter roads and highways to remove all vehicles.

Comment: @JaredK - oops!  I think you are right.

Comment: @reirab: Do you know if there's a way to force switching between aerial and satellite imagery? There used to be a few years ago, but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: @Mehrdad Not that I'm aware of. For me, it usually just switches at a certain zoom level (at least in the areas where aerial photography is available at all.)

Comment: @JaredK I definitely think it's a multiple-exposure effect, not chromatic aberration. See https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78317/chromatic-aberration-or-multiple-exposures

Answer (score 8):

This is a common occurrence with airplanes on Google maps. Google overlays multiple scans taken seconds apart from satellite imagery to get the best image quality.

This works very well for stationary objects, such as buildings and land structures but results in multiple images of high speed objects, such as airplanes. Sometimes this effect is visible even with cars on a highway.

Answer (score 1):

What looks like tampering is actually multiple exposures, plus cross-channel rolling shutter (the color fringes).  If you measure the spacing of the aircraft images and the size of the fringes, you can infer that it's one aircraft slowing down after touchdown.  You can even see the puffs of smoke that show the main gear touching down before the nose wheel.  Here's a [careful analysis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/95185/24666).