# How did this plane get into this position and orientation?

Tags: airport

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJJcq.jpg]
<sup>taken from https://www.google.com/maps/@-33.9418465,151.174248,945m/data=!3m1!1e3</sup>

A) Landing from the east, some crosswind and touchdown off center?
B) Taking off from the east, some crosswind "
C) Landed from the south, for some reason turning left onto runway 27R, heading to international terminal "Global Exchange"?

Comment: Looks very much like a left turn to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A is out of the question. This would have been a VERY late and unlikely touchdown. Option B is possible, but option C is the correct answer, especially when zooming in: https://www.google.com/maps/@-33.9413253,151.1742231,145m/data=!3m1!1e3

Judging by the tire marks on the runway (which appear to go left) this is clearly not the first aircraft (an Air China A330 if you wondered) to perform this maneuver.

The reason is clear: taxiway A2 (the high-speed exit just before the runway intersection) appears to be closed for maintenance: https://www.google.com/maps/@-33.9433411,151.17333,205m/data=!3m1!1e3

This is also evident by the following NOTAM:

> Q) YMMM/QMXLC/IV/M /A /000/999/3357S15111E A) **YSSY** B) 18/09/21 13:00
>   C) 18/09/23 19:00 D) DAILY 1300-1900 EXC SAT E) TWY A BTN TWY G AND
>   TWY L NOT AVBL DUE WIP **TWY A2, TWY A3, TWY A4, TWY B5, TWY B6, TWY B7
>   AND TWY B9 NOT AVBL** TWY B3, TWY B4, TWY K AND TWY B8 BTN RWY 16R/34L
>   AND TWY B NOT AVBL TWY H BTN TWY Y AND TWY A NOT AVBL TWY J MAX 52M
>   WINGSPAN TWY B BTN TWY G AND TWY B10 MAX 36M WINGSPAN REFER METHOD OF
>   WORKING PLAN 17/003

Comment: Further evidence against A: no disjoint colours visible (like in https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52086/4108 or https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/51998/why-does-this-satellite-image-of-an-airplane-in-motion-show-red-green-and-blue)